# Wordpress paypal gateway integration plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal

I used several plugins which enable to integrate paypal gateway and wordpress.
But I want to find a plugin which enable us to buy and comeback to same page with updated status.
For instance, he cancelled it or successfully paid it so that I can refer that response to that order.
How can I do this?

Easy Paypal Gateway, Wordpress Paypal not works. 
I don't want static return url. Must back to same page with its transaction status.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're looking for that's special, but the most popular option for Wordpress seems to be WooCommerce, with their PayPal module: https://woocommerce.com/woocommerce-and-paypal/